# Finding the eigenvalues of this 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: Click here for problem solution attempt]

I entered this matrix into matlab and did the `eig(a)` function and I'm supposed to be getting roots -1, 1, and 3, but after working the problem out, I seem to be far from it.

Comment: for starters, you switched the sign of the 8 on your fourth line

Comment: Double-check what you typed into matlab. I get $1,-1,-2$ for the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the 4th row of your working,

It is supposed to be (-7-$\lambda$)(-6+$\lambda$-6$\lambda$+$\lambda^2$-8) not (-7-$\lambda$)[-6+$\lambda$-6$\lambda$+$\lambda^2$+8).

Hope you can continue to work it from here.

Comment: Aah. That's embarrassing. Changing that 1 sign screwed the whole thing up big time. Thanks for catching that.